# Retrieve a count from a one-to-many relationship even if there are no rows at the "many"-end of the relationship

Tags: postgresql

I have the following table, `company_likes`:

```
                     Table "public.company_likes"
   Column   |              Type              |       Modifiers        
------------+--------------------------------+------------------------
 company_id | integer                        | not null
 user_id    | integer                        | not null
 created_at | timestamp(0) without time zone | not null default now()
Indexes:
    "company_likes_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (company_id, user_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "company_likes_company_id_foreign" FOREIGN KEY (company_id) REFERENCES companies(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    "company_likes_user_id_foreign" FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

The structure of the `companies` table is not important as you can deduce whatever needed for the purpose of this question from the foreign keys details in the `\d company_likes` output.

I am trying to fetch the number of likes for a set of companies. I tried the following:

```
select company_id, count(company_id) as likes_count from company_likes where company_id in (1,2,3,4) group by company_id;
```

And per [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18397570/1673776), I have also tried this:

```
select company_id, count(company_id) as likes_count from company_likes
left join companies on companies.id = company_likes.company_id
where company_id in (1,2,3,4)
group by company_id;
```

However the output in both cases is an empty result. I would have liked something like this

```
 company_id | likes_count  
------------+-------------
 1          | 0            
 2          | 0            
 3          | 0            
 4          | 0
```

What query should I use to get a result like this?

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
select 
  C.id
, count( CL.company_id ) likes_count
from companies C
  left join company_likes CL on C.id = CL.company_id 
group by C.id 
order by C.id ;
```

See [dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=62a85a122235e9fb8199b467371a37c9) (Postgres 9.6).

```
-- test tables and data
create table companies ( id int4 primary key ) ;

insert into companies ( id ) values (1),(2),(3),(4);

select * from companies ;

id
1
2
3
4

create table company_likes (
  company_id int4 references companies( id )
);

insert into company_likes ( company_id ) values (1),(4),(4),(4),(4) ;

select * from company_likes ;

company_id
1
4
4
4
4
```

Query

```
select 
  C.id
, count( CL.company_id ) likes_count
from companies C
  left join company_likes CL on C.id = CL.company_id 
group by C.id 
order by C.id ;

id  likes_count
1   1
2   0
3   0
4   4
```

Answer (score 0):

Start out with the `VALUES` that you want to be included.

```
SELECT company_id, count(company_id) as likes_count
FROM (VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4))
  AS gs(id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN company_likes USING (id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN companies
  ON companies.id = company_likes.company_id
GROUP BY company_id;
```

But I'm not sure that's a stellar idea anyway, I have to question why you're selecting IDs that may not be there.

## UPDATE

I see what the problem is in your query you have

```
where company_id in (1,2,3,4)
```

However, `company_id` is only there if the join succeeds. There is nothing to join it against if there are no likes, so you need,

```
where companies.id in (1,2,3,4)
```

Comment: I have an API entry that needs to return likes count to the user for a specific set of posts. Since I need to keep record of likes (who liked what and when), I have the `company_likes` table. I need to retrieve the likes for a specific set of company listings and have `0` for listings that have no likes (i.e. there is no row having `company_id = <id>` in the `company_likes` table). How should I do that in a better way?

Comment: There is no better way. SQL is query language. It queries data. What you need is something to prepare a result set for your app's end point. That's not SQL. If nothing matches your query, SQL doesn't return a row. `SELECT 1 WHERE false;` should return `null`. You *want* a result back, so you have to work against the system by making sure that condition is never false. The *only* way to do this is to wedge those values into a table. Most end points do not return 0 if the target doesn't exist. They throw 404.

Comment: When you go on StackOverflow and go to a question, does StackOverflow return a 404 if the question has 0 votes?

Comment: @Victor the problem here is that your company doesn't exist. Not that the likes themselves return 0. If the companies existed, they'd already return exactly what you want.

Comment: @Victor I see what the problem is you're querying on company_id and not companies.id.